# Limit file size on Dokan FileSystem

Tags: c#, dokan

I'm trying to make a virtual file system using the C# version of Dokan.
What I want to do right now is to set the max limit of a file for my filesystem, for example, the filesystem can't have a file with more than 2GB.

At the moment I'm doing this on Operation SetEndOfFile but I can only give DiskFull error and I want to return something like NTStatus.FileTooLarge, but when I do that the filesystem simply ignore that return.

Is there any options to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the offset of the `WriteFile` function, if offset is bigger than 2GB - you return `NtStatus.FileTooLarge`.

Also, you should check the `buffer.Length` too, in case when you edit the file on the disk - it doesn't chop it into smaller buffered chunks, instead the entire file is put into a one buffer. In this scenario, you should find a way not to destroy the file, because the `CleanUp` will be called immediately after returning `NtStatus.FileTooLarge` from `WriteFile` method with `info.DeleteOnClose` set to true.